# Find type of interface member in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, runtime

Let's say I had the following code:

```
interface Members {
  authenticated: boolean,
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type Prop = keyof Members;

const handlers = {
  get(_: Members, prop: Prop) {
    return typeof prop === "boolean";
  },
  set(_: Members, prop: Prop, val: any) {
    return true;
  }
};

const ls = new Proxy<Members>({} as Members, handlers);

console.log(ls.authenticated);
```

This prints `false` instead of `true` because the type of `prop` is always a string.

However, I would like to get the type of the actual prop in the interface itself, such that `typeof prop` would return "string" if the passed in prop was `name`.

A hacky solution to this would be to create an empty reference object and fill it with random values of the corresponding type, like this:

```
let reference: Members = {
  authenticated: false,
  name: "who cares",
  age: 42
}
```

And then at runtime in the `get` function we could do this instead:

```
return typeof reference[prop] === "boolean";
```

But that just seems like such a gross solution, having to create an example object just to check the types. Is there a better way?

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime. Which means at runtime, you can't get a string derived purely from a type. Whatever your goal is, you may want to rethink your approach here.

Comment: So the ideal solution is what I posted above? Just filling a random object of that type with garbage data and referencing that?

Comment: It sounds more like you want a "schema" (like [json schema](https://json-schema.org/)), which is basically types made out of runtime values, combined with runtime functions that let you interrogate those values. Typescript doesn't really offer anything related to this out of the box, though. (Don't take this as a library recommendation. I'm not sure what you should use specifically)

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand that link.. Also I am probably not going to use a library for something I can replicate in a couple lines of code..